# Horizontal Collision Detection Using Crafty.js Game Engine

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, craftyjs

I'm trying to build a breakout-style type of game with continuous 
vertical player movement and only horizontal input. I need to detect 
if a brick is hit on the sides or top/bottom. Without detecting that, 
I haven't been able to stop the player movement from overlapping the 
bricks that aren't destroyed. I tried to detect which edge of the 
polygon the player entity was hitting using this (calls the first function when a collision is detected and the second when `justHit` is set to false):

```
.onHit("brick", function() { 
    if (data[0]['normal']['y']==0) { 
        reverseDirection(); 
    } 
    else { 
        this._hspeed = 0; 
    } 
}, function() { 
    this._hspeed = 3; 
})
```

But I'm getting 2 problems: the 'y' datahit value changes when the 
player entity reaches the corner of a brick, and for some reason the 
brick component is pretty much ignored if there are 2 bricks side by 
side.

- I've posted some stripped down code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XurrR/)
- You can see examples of the current detection with hitdata 
  conditionals [here](http://marcripley.com/diamonds/)
- And an example of the original collision bug with [no movement 
  restraints when colliding on a brick edge](http://marcripley.com/diamonds/coll_bug.html)

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem, and the example links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw multiple hitboxes on the entity, and then depending on which box triggers the collision perform your specific action.